# Apache rewrite or proxy with redirect of internal server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am trying to use Apache as a proxy for an internal tomcat server, but the tomcat server performs a redirect that got me crazy

I first tried **mod_proxy** through:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8045/bv-via-web/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8045/bv-via-web/
```

When accessing `/` (root) the internal server performs a redirect to `/bv-via-web/hola` which doesn't exist. It should redirect to `/hola`. How can I achieve this through the Apache config?

As a workaround I though I add the following:

```
ProxyPass /bv-via-web/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8045/bv-via-web/
ProxyPassReverse /bv-via-web/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8045/bv-via-web/
```

But that doesn't work as it will extend the url to an internal request of `bv-via-web/bv-via-web/hola`. So basically I want to change the url but don't know how that is possible with mod_proxy.

I then tried **mod_rewrite**, with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bv-via-web/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P,L]
```

But then when I open the root of the website it performs a redirect and `http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/hola` appears in the browser address.

I don't understand, as it should work as an internal proxy due to the [P] flag.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `P` flag does not need `L` flag since it is included. Also, you must avoid leading slash in your rule. This rule should work as expected: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P]`. Every request such as `domain.com/hello/world` should be forwarded to `http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/hello/world`

Comment: Thanks justin. However, I tried your modification before (just now again), and got in the log file " "GET /bv-via-web// HTTP/1.1" 404". That was my reason for adding the slash. And when I modify it by removing the leading slahs the before $1 (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web$1 [P]) the browser will try to redirect and in the browser address bar appears: "127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/" as explained in my post (log file redirect: GET /bv-via-web/ HTTP/1.1" 302).

Comment: What about this rule? `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Such it's not forwarded to the 127.0.0.1 as mentioned above.
So the total config snippet is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bv-via-web/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8040/bv-via-web/$1 [P]
```